# Getting mongoerror once the nodejs is started

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in node and getting the following error once I start node server.

```
*** API is running on environment: DEV - listening on port 3019!
Unhandled rejection MongoError: cannot index parallel arrays [occupations] [types]
    at Function.MongoError.create (/var/www/api-dev/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at /var/www/api-dev/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1096:80
    at /var/www/api-dev/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Fields --

```
types:[
            {type:String,require:true,index:true}
        ],

occupations:[
            {
                company:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Company",index:true},
                position:{type:String,require:false,index:true},
                department:{type:String,require:false,index:true}
            }
        ],
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one with `occupations` and `types` arrays being used in a compound index.

Comment: @AlexBlex How can I know the field names or schema name where the compound index has been used.

Comment: `occupations` and `types` are the field names.

Comment: ahh got it.. Let me check in which schema they are in. Thanks

Comment: So those 2 fields are arrays and the index is set to true for both of them. Why can't mongo handle compound indexing.

Comment: It can, but T&Cs apply. No more than 1 array per index.

Comment: I have updated the post with the array fields. So in each document I have 2 arrays. What sort of T&Cs I need to apply. Is it related with the fields order. Currently `types` has been defined before `occupations` in the schema but in the document it's the opposite.

Comment: Sorry mate, you don't need to apply anything but read [the T&Cs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations): **No more than 1 array per index** I don't think I can put it simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link :)

Comment: np, just to make it clear - the indices you posted in the question are okay. They are legitimate multikey indices on a single field. The compound ones are defined on schema level. Something like `schemaName.index({ types: 1, occupations: 1 })`, where both types and occupations are in the same index. Such indices are not supported by the database.

Comment: Exactly. There is a line where I can see both arrays are in same index. :)